# Run JMeter samplers asynchronously

Tags: websocket, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have 2 Thread Groups in my test plan that run sequentially.

```
TestPlan
|-Thread1
|-Thread2
```

In Thread 1 I do some samples that open the 1st WebSocket connection for the User1
In Thread 2 I do some samples that open the 2nd WebSocket connection for the User2

```
TestPlan
|-Thread1
|--HTTP Sample 1
|--HTTP Sample 2
|--WebSocket Connection Open for User1
|-Thread2
|--HTTP Sample 1
|--HTTP Sample 2
|--WebSocket Connection Open for User2
```

When I open the WS connection for User2 the server must send the message to User1 that User2 has been connected.

How to verify if User1 gets the response from the server after User2 has connected to WebSocket by his credentials?

I tried different approaches but it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case if "the server must send the message" I can only think of using i.e. [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) to periodically check the message from the server by User 1.

Add a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) which will check presence of the message and extract the message content and compare it to the anticipated one using a suitable JMeter Function like [__jexl3](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)